# FileNotFoundError trying to read a datafile with Jupyter in Pycharm

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm, jupyter

I'm new to Jupyter and I'm trying to read a .csv file without luck.

I have these files:
`data/mydatafile.csv`
`scripts/myscript.py`
`scripts/mynotebook.ipynb`

In `myscript.py` I can read the datafile successfully by referring to `../data/mydatafile.csv`. But trying to do the same in `mynotebook.ipynb` leads to a `FileNotFoundError: File b'../data/mydatafile.csv' does not exist`.

What can I do to make this work? I'm writing my code in Pycharm if it matters.

Version information:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Run Configuration, make sure the 'Working directory' field agrees with where you are specifying your relative path.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't think I can see a run configuration for `mynotebook.ipynb`, actually. Should I see one? I run the Jupyter server by hitting shift+enter.

Comment: In PyCharm, there should be a green triangle 'play' button on the toolbar. If you click the dropdown to the immediate left of this, you should see an 'Edit Configurations... choice. That pops up the window I was talking about with the 'Working directory' field.

Answer (score 0):

@fiveclubs gives the right view.
Actually, in your Jupiter script, you should check your "Working directory". There are two methods to get it.

1. In the head of your Jupiter script, 

   `import os
   print(os.getcwd())`

   and then, add necessary prefix-name of your directory.
   I have the same problem because there is a lack of a folder name.
2. In your script's `Configurations` Window to check your `Working directory`

In summary, I think the first method is better.

Hope it would be helpful.